# Eliminating the option of choosing the installation folder for users

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

Iam trying to make a basic msi installer and dont want the user to choose the installation folder i.e., I dont want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNskS.png) to be shown to the users
can someone tell me how to do this?

Can I do this with the basic setup project in visual studio?